# search an element in the array of objects

Tags: javascript

Is there any javascript function to search an element in the array of objects. 
We have sort function in javascript to sort an array of objects.

```
[
    {name:'a', value:'1'},
    {name:'b', value:'2'},
    {name:'c', value:'3'},
    {name:'d', value:'4'},
    {name:'e', value:'5'}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ES5 [`Array.prototype.filter`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.20) method ([MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter)). For example, to reduce the array to only those objects with a `name` property of "a":

```
var result = yourArray.filter(function(elem) {
    return elem.name === "a";
});
console.log(result); //[Object -> name: 'a', value: '1']
```

This is not supported by older browsers, but there are plenty of polyfills available for it.